# R stringr: str_match ignoring text between expressions

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a string containing some text like this:

```
Base_Text <- "John will sell Apple stock"
```

If I want to extract the name of the company I can use something similar to:

```
str_match(Base_Text, "will sell [:upper:][a-z]+ stock")
```

But I'm having problems when the text becomes more elaborate, for example:

```
New_Text <- "John will sell, given the current situation of the market, all of his Apple stock"
```

I'm looking for a regex that ignores everything between "sell" and an uppercase word which I will suppose to be the name of the company:

```
str_match(New_Text, "will sell [ignore everything in between] [:upper:][a-z]+ stock")
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use the following regular expression to match all words following "sell" that begin with a capital letter: `(?!.*\bsell\b)\b[A-Z][a-z]+`. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/hcJ3Hf/1/) The negative lookahead causes the regex's string pointer to move to the location between `'s'` and `'e'` in `'sell'`, as the lookahead is satisfied at that point. (I may need to write `\\b` rather than `\b`, but R's not my forte.)

Comment: `"will sell\\b.*?\\b[[:upper:]][a-z]+ stock"`?

Comment: @Wiktor, it's curious (nothing more) that you wrote `[[:upper:]]` rather than `[A-Z]`, yet `[a-z]` rather than `[[:lower:]]`. :-) Wait, don't you mean to have a capture group?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Copy/paste from a mobile phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this brute force solution which could be clearly improved I'm sure :

```
library(stringr)
New_str <- "John will sell, given the current situation of the market, all of his Apple stock"
start <- str_locate(New_str, pattern = "sell")[2]
end <- str_locate_all(New_str,
           pattern = "[:upper:][a-z]+")[[1]][2, 1]
paste(substr(New_str, 1, start + 1), substr(New_str, end - 1, str_count(New_str)), sep = "")
```